# Scala - How to do map only for some elements in the list without filter?

Tags: scala

I have function which for any input returns String `black`. I want to change every element in the list which does not equal `yellow` to black and return it as new list.

Using filter and map it removes elements from the list which I don't want to do.

I also want to keep it using functional programming, lambdas not old for loop. I know I could give the filter condition in the map function but I want to avoid that

```
def change_color(color:String):String = {
return "black"
}

val cats = Seq("pink","blue","yellow")
```

So the output should be

```
Seq("black","black","yellow")
```

Comment: Why don't you use map function? You can check it element yellow or not inside the map and return an unchanged element if it is yellow.

Comment: `cats.map(color => if (color == "yellow") "yellow" else "black")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common application of a map function over a collection. In your case a List. What is the essence of a map:

```
def change_color(color: String) : String =  
   if (color == "yellow") "yellow" else "black"


def map[A, B](list: List[A)(f: A => B): List[B] = {
   ???
}
```

It takes a function from A to B and applies to each element of the collection, so, in your case your function is String => String

```
cats.map(change_color _)

cats.map(el => change_color(el))
```

This is just the beginning of working with Scala collections and their functions. From here you can experiment with folds, flatmap, grouping, parallel processing, etc...

Comment: I see. I change the function definition

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a `Partial Function` to transform this sequence

```
Seq("pink", "blue", "yellow")
                    .collect { case y @ "yellow" => y; case _ => "black" }
```

This would be more concise.

Comment: If you don't want to filter collection better use map instead of collect

Comment: @AlekseyIsachenkov Is this just about performance, or are there other reasons not to use `collect` in this case?

Comment: Yes, it's more performant. Collect is nearly equal to the filter and map.